# "popover" problems on twitter bootstrap css/javascript library

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to implement popover javascript on my site with twitter bootstrap and i couldn't. If anyone could help me with my code, i would appreciate a lot. thanks in advance for that.

```
<head>
...
    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/html5.js"></script>  
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap-tabs.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap-alerts.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap-twipsy.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="1.3.0/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css" />

...
</head>
<body>
...

                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="active" id="dwcenter_iso">
                                        <table class="zebra-striped">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Arquivo</th>
                                                    <th>Tamanho</th>
                                                    <th>Data</th>
                                                    <th>md5</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a href="download.php">nimbus-opensource-backup-1.1.iso</a> <span class="label success">new</span></td>
                                                    <td>332M</td>
                                                    <td>16/09/11</td>

<!-- HERE GOES -->
                                                 <td><a href="#" class="btn danger" rel="popover" title="md5 Check Sum" data-content="343453453453453rfef34">ver</a>
                                                       <script>
                                                                $(function () {
                                                          $('a[rel=popover]')
                                                            .popover({
                                                              html: true
                                                            })
                                                            .click(function(e) {
                                                              e.preventDefault()
                                                            })
                                                        })
                                                      </script> 
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>nimbus-opensource-backup-1.0.iso <span class="label important">deprecated</span></td>
                                                    <td>332M</td>
                                                    <td>10/08/11</td>
                                                    <td>ver</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>nimbus-opensource-backup-0.9beta.iso <span class="label important">deprecated</span></td>
                                                    <td>380MB</td>
                                                    <td>25/09/10</td>
                                                    <td>ver</td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>


...
</body>
```

i have tried "html: true" and the bootstrap doc example "offset: 10".
It does shows the red danger button, but nothing happens then (the popover doesn't work).

And something else, how could i implement this on the TD element of the table rather than the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change these 2 scripts around as popover is an extension of twipsy and needs to be loaded first...

```
<script src="scripts/bootstrap-twipsy.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
```

You don't need to set html to true, here's mine with options you can change if you wish

```
$(function(){
   $(".btn").popover({
       offset: 5,
       placement: 'left'
    });
});
```

Comment: this worked smoothly. But what does exactly do the offset attribute?

Comment: @Pabluez you can see all the options for popover here: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover

Comment: Nowadays, you need to include 'tooltip.js' instead of 'twipsy.js.'

Comment: It does not mention what the offset attribute stands for in popovers..can anyone tell what it is used for?

Comment: The offset attribute is used to push the popover 'x' amount of pixels away from the click target, although the documentation has been removed from v2 so not sure if it still works.